# Install mongodb extension with PHP 7.0.8 in Ubuntu 16

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04, pecl

I have installed `mongodb` extension for `php 5.5` in Ubuntu 14.0 with this command `pecl install mongodb` now i want to install `mogodb` extension for `php 7.0.8` in `ubuntu 16` when i run the above command it return `pecl command not found` 
any one could help me

Comment: `apt-get install php-mongodb`
 package contains in default repository

Comment: no need to add extension in php.ini ?

Comment: Execute above command in console.